# Electron.js menu rendering the drop-down menu over main menu item text

Tags: menu, electron, menubar

I'm running this basic Electron app on Windows 11 and wondering if this visual behavior for the menu system is intended because it sure is eye-wateringly janky. Note how the main menu item text is partially obscured due to the top of the drop-down box being positioned halfway into the menu bar area. Should it not take the manu bar height into account? Checked the Electron.js docs and cannot find anything in the Menu section for controlling render positioning for menu drop-downs.

Code for this app is via:

```
npx create-electron-app@latest my-electron-app
```

[image]